# how to $rootScope.$broadcast event in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

Does anybody have a working example of how to $rootScope.$broadcast event in Protractor tests?

I know Protractor is not used for this, and that i should use Karma for unit testing. But the situation is that I need to broadcast an event in Protractor test. For this i need to get the $rootScope, i guess. But i do not know how to do it in Protractor and I failed to find an answer in the internet after long hours of searching.

I guess the below regards unit testing. There is no inject in protractor.

```
var rootScope;
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
}));

$rootScope.$broadcast("EVENT_TO_TEST", other, possible, args);
```

Hope the solution exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could run a script within the browser this way:

```
browser.executeScript("
  angular.element('body').injector().get('$rootScope').$broadcast(...);
");
```

Or using a different syntax to get the root scope:

```
browser.executeScript("
  angular.element('body').scope().$root.$broadcast(...);
");
```

You can replace `body` by whichever element contain a scope.

Comment: floribon, you cannot even emagine how much you helped me. Thank you so much for your very fast reply, man. IOU

Comment: Glad it helped, that's what SO is for. Feel free to accept/+1 the answer :)